# SharePoint Permissions Reset Everyday

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-server, project-server

We are using SharePoint 2007 to track the defects.

During the project planning not all resources are involved, later we give permissions for other resources to access the list.

However these people lose the permissions every evening.

We are forced to grant the permissions daily through Project Server.

Some help from you guys will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.!!

Answer (score 1):

I would check couple of things to identify the root cause.

1. check the ULS logs / Event log during the time frame when you think permission removed.
2. any special timer job / schedule task running on the servers?
3. If user profile is configured then check when the synchronization job runs?
4. all users are part of same domain? did they left and rejoin the company?
5. all users are part of a group or you added them individually.

please check the below post for reference may help you.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/projectserver/en-US/6cca65d8-fb40-4844-9999-b8ff968b6ec0/project-server-user-automatically-gets-removed-from-the-advanced-permissionpwa-site-page-and

and this one,

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/a74abe78-6aa3-4267-a577-e8418193c2ae/permissions-keep-getting-removed-automatically?forum=winserverDS

Answer (score 0):

Project Server synchronizes permissions when the sites are published or permission settings are changed by REMOVING the users from the site then REAPPLYING the permissions configured on the categories and security groups. This means that when you break inheritance and add specific permissions on a list the user will be removed from the sub-site.

The best way to guarantee that the users won't lose permissions is to assign them to a task in the project (only adding them to the project team will grant them read-only permissions)

Another alternative is to assign the permissions to a Site group, created for the project. When the permission is assigned to a group, the removal of the permission does not force the user to be removed from the sub-site. This alternative might reach Sharepoint's recommended maximum number of groups per site collection if you have too many projects (i've had it happen)

This behavior is present in Project Server 2010 as well.